# How to create init<dbName>.ora file?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I wanted to create data base. I downloaded *Oracle Database 12c* and *Oracel SQL Devloper.* I set environment variable ORACLE_SID using CMD (as administrator). I did the same actions with ORACLE_HOME. Another step was create Windows service. After this step i create file initHadeanDb.ora where SID=HadeanDb. Interior mentioned file:

```
control_files = (E:\app\JKowalski\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\dbs\control01.ora, 
E:\app\JKowalski\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\dbs\control02.ora, 
E:\app\JKowalski\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\dbs\control03.ora) 
undo_management = auto 
db_name         = ora10 
db_block_size       = 8192
```

But if i' m trying continue process i gave this:

[image]

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: please provide the full path where you created the file initHadeanDb.ora

Answer (score 2):

You can use Database Configuration Assistant (DBCA) to create a database. 
This will take care for the proper init.ora, controlfiles and datafiles for your database. 
When you have installed the binaries already, you will find DBCA at 
Start - (All) Programs - Oracle - HOME_NAME - Configuration and Migration Tools -  Database Configuration Assistant.

You can use DBCA to create a set of scripts only (without actually creating a database). These scripts can then be adapted or you run every single command manually.
For this take care **not** to chose a template based installation in DBCA but pure custom. In the last screen, before DBCA starts to create the DB, you can save the scripts, and after they are created just cancel DBCA.

For details, please read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADMQS/installing-oracle-database-creating-database.htm#ADMQS0231).

Comment: I used DBCA. It was good idea. Thanks for your help. Back to my question: problem didn't appear when I used "STARTUP NOMOUNT PFILE={path to the init<SID>.ora}" instead "STARTUP NOMOUNT".

Comment: I have another problem. I created database (thanks to you) and opened in Oracle sql developer on the same PC, where is database. But I don't know how to connect from other PC. In my PC I used hostname localhost and port 1521. How to get hostname and port necessary to logon on PC different from PC with running database? (username, password and SID can be the same right?)

Comment: That's not how stackoverflow works.
Please mark this particular question as answered. 
When you have new questions, first do a valid research. If the question still exists, raise it as a new question in SO. Show what you have, (e.g. config files) what you try to achieve, what's the errors / unexpected results and what are your expected results.